# Datagridview has readonly rows, still want to go to row enter event?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

My row enter events are not triggering when the row is readonly. I need an event when the user selects a row so I can populate another grid. Row enter seems to not be triggering is there a way to make the rowenter trigger or a different event I can use?

Someone suggested I set each cell in the row to readonly instead of the row and that might fix it, that would change a lot of the program and I feel like it still wouldn't work, I don't want to do it unless someone can confirm it will work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the click event of the data grid and get the selected row properties from there? Sorry if its no help, just worth a shot!

Hope it helps!